# Jasperreport about Hyperlink to second report

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports

I hava two report in the this file `C:\tomcat\webapps\vivicloud\vivitrend\src\main\jasperreports`: `main report "dailyOrderReport.jrxml"` / `second report "dailyOrderReportDetail2.jrxml"`

Main report have a `${sequence}` field. I want to click the main report `${sequence}` field can transfer parameter and link to "dailyOrderReportDetail2".

In the sequence filed I config the hyperlink and detail is

```
Hyperlink Target :self

Hyperlink Type: ReportExecution

Link parameter :

Parameter Name       Expression 

_report             "repo:dailyOrderReportDetail2"

sequence            $F{sequence}
```

But can not to link to `dailyOrderReportDetail2`.

Comment: maybe change in your config target to blank.

Answer (score 1):

In what you are trying to do i think you should skip the "repo:" in front of your linked report. And check that the relative path to your second report `dailyOrderReportDetail2.jrxml` is correct.

Check the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984283/hyperlink-in-jasper-reports-across-subreport) for a step by step mini tutorial on how to do it (using servlets), or see a similar approach [on this blog](http://alexandru-ersenie.com/2009/10/22/passing-parameters-between-jasper-reports-using-ireport-and-jasperserver/).

Hope this helps you get in the right direction, or at least gives you some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If both report are already running in JasperReport Server then problem must be in relative path of second report.
     just check relative path of the second report must be written in red color and give the full path like:-

```
         "repo:/path of the second report "
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but might help someone else in the future.

I'm guessing you mean kind of like a drill-down report.  Make sure all the parameters are exactly the same in the second report that need to pass over from the first report.

*NOTE: You will not use the .jrxml file of the "sub report".  The second report needs to be actually published with input controls and all.*

Click the field you want to be the hyperlink
Click hyperlink in properties tab
`Link Target` : Blank
`Link Type` : ReportExecution
Parameters (very important)
1. `Parameter`: _report 
`Expression`: path of published report **(not .jrxml)**
2. `parameter`: your choice : 
`Expression`: Whatever carries over

now when you publish this main report and you click on the hyperlink, it will run the second report with the parameters set.